# SSL and Access-control configuration

Tags: mongodb

We are building a MongoDB cluster with an SSL configuration, but now I need to set up roles and privileges which I can't do without setting Access Control to enable state. When I do that, the SSL connection between nodes is gone and they can't communicate - is it possible to configure both SSL and Access Control? And if YES how should I do that?

Comment: How will the nodes authenticate each other?

Comment: with SSL , 5 nodes , 2 data , 2 config and 1 routing  ,                                                           tls:
     mode: requireTLS
     certificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/includesprivatekey.pem
     CAFile: /etc/pki/ca.pem                                                                                           
   security:
       authorization: enabled                                                                                          
    what is strange is that when I adding the above security .... parameter the two data nodes mode become   RECOVERING

Comment: Did you add the [clusterAuthMode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.clusterAuthMode) setting to tell the nodes to use certificates for authentication?

Comment: Hi , Probably to use this setting I need to have "clusterFile" , I have 3 SSL files , ca.pem,ild-tlv-mongodb02.key,ild-tlv-mongodb02.crt  , what is a "clusterFile" do I need to add its definition to all cluster nodes , conf, query and data ?

Comment: If no clusterFile is provided and clusterAuthMode is set to use certificates, the nodes will attempt to use the PEMKeyFile.  If you have a separate certificate for authenticating the ndoes, definitely add clusterFile with that filename.

Comment: how can I set clusterAuthMode  to use certificates , can you give me an example please .

Comment: Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.clusterAuthMode -  3 of the 4 valid settings involve certificates, and it further links to a longer explanation of using certificates for internal authentication